# How to change gstreamer Element property

Tags: gstreamer, fullscreen, wayland

I want to make the gstreamer app full screen.
Waylandsink property has fullscreen, how do I change it?
Or is there a way to go full screen without changing the Waylandsink property?

Comment: Please add what programming language you're trying to use (or if you're trying to use gst-launch). Depending on the answer, there's a lot of [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973081/how-to-use-properties-on-gstreamer) out there already..

Comment: The programming language is c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting by command
`$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/root/testpi.h264 ! decodebin ! vspmfilter ! waylandsink fullscreen=TRUE`

When writing in code

```
`#define INPUT_FILE    "/home/root/testpi.h264"
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *parser, *decoder, *filter, *sink;
const gchar *input_file = INPUT_FILE;

gst_init(&argc, &argv);

/* Create gstreamer elements */
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video-play");
source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "file-source");
parser = gst_element_factory_make ("h264parse", "h264-parser");
decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("omxh264dec", "h264-decoder");
filter = gst_element_factory_make ("vspmfilter", "filter");
sink = gst_element_factory_make ("waylandsink", "video-output");

/* Set input video file for source element */
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", input_file, NULL);

/* Set element property */
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(sink),"fullscreen",TRUE,NULL);

/* Add all elements into the pipeline */
/* pipeline---[ file-source + h264-parser + h264-decoder + filter + video-output ] */
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, parser, decoder, filter, sink, NULL);

/* Link the elements together */
/* file-source -> h264-parser -> h264-decoder -> filter -> video-output */
if (gst_element_link_many (source, parser, decoder, filter, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
        g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (pipeline);
        return -1;
}

 /* Set the pipeline to "playing" state */
 g_print ("Now playing: %s\n", input_file);
 if (gst_element_set_state (pipeline,
  GST_STATE_PLAYING) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
   g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
   gst_object_unref (pipeline);
   return -1;
 }
g_print ("Running...\n");
while(1)
{
;
}
```

`